# Python, How can I change the marker size and its alpha created/plotted by/with model?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
df=df_date_yellow[["Date of Travel",'Number of Passengers']]
df.columns = ['ds', 'y']
df['ds']= to_datetime(df['ds'])
model = Prophet()
# fit the model
model.fit(df)
# define the period for which we want a prediction
future = list()
for i in range(1, 13):
    date = '2019-%02d' % i
    future.append([date])
future = pd.DataFrame(future)
future.columns = ['ds']
future['ds']= to_datetime(future['ds'])
# use the model to make a forecast
forecast = model.predict(future)
# summarize the forecast
print(forecast[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']].head())
# plot forecast
model.plot(forecast)
plt.gca().get_lines()[0].set_color("yellow")
plt.title("Yellow Cabs Number of Passengers and Its Forecast For The Next Year", size=15)
plt.xlabel("Dates", size=15)
plt.ylabel("Number of Passengers", size=15)
plt.show()
```

[Here is the end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6CVP.png)

I want to make this yellow points to be bigger and make their alpha better. How can I do it?

Comment: Please add the image directly to the post.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code example work for you.  Change marker size or color as what you like.

```
plt.plot(x, y, marker='.', markersize=20, markeredgecolor='black', alpha=0.4)
```

Comment: model.plot(forecast)
plt.gca().get_lines()[0].set_color("yellow")     plot function is udes after model created and plotting accordingly even make the dots yellow I used the second line in this comment, I think it is more complicated, yours suggestions does not work for my case

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your call to `set_color` in : `plt.gca().get_lines()[0].set_color("yellow")`, you can directly use the method `set(color="yellow",alpha = 0.8)` as described in the documentation of matplotlib [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set).

Hope this helps !